# Trying to link static into the shared library - got Undefined reference

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

My goal is to use api from static library within source of shared library, by using cmake 3.4.

Very simple code for static library

```cpp
// Header
class Structure 
{
public:
    int sum( int a, int b );
    int mul( int a, int b ) { return a * b; }
};
// Source
#include "Include/Structure.hpp"

int Structure::sum( int a, int b ) { 
    return a + b;
}
```

.. and usage in source of shared class

```cpp
Structure* s = new Structure();
s->sum(3, 4);
s->mul(3, 4);
```

Cmake file for static lib:

```cpp
project(MyStaticLibrary)
include_directories(Include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})
set_target_properties( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fPIC")
```

Cmake file for shared lib:

```cpp
include_directories( ${static_lib_src_DIR}/Include )
add_subdirectory( ${static_lib_src_DIR} ${static_lib_build_DIR} )
add_library( MyStaticLibrary STATIC ${static_lib_src_DIR})
set_target_properties( MyStaticLibrary PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set_target_properties( MyStaticLibrary PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/...../libMyStaticLibrary.a )

add_library( native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)
add_dependencies(native-lib MyStaticLibrary)
target_link_libraries( native-lib MyStaticLibrary )
```

Error message on linking shared library : undefined reference to 'Structure::sum(int, int)'

Comment: According to assigning `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property in the second project, you want `MyStaticLibrary` to be IMPORTED library. But you forgot *IMPORTED* keyword in the `add_library` call.

Comment: No, I want it to be build as dependency. Btw, commented out this line and got the same error.